# Join DataFrames based on multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe, join, datatable

I want to join two tables. The one is a DataTable `DT_1` and the other a DataFrame `DF_2`. The columns `name` and `value` in `DT_1` are related to the rows and columns of the `DF_2`. The output would be the `DT_1` with a new column `expr` consists of the corresponding values sourced from the `DF_2`.

```
View(DT_1)
CHR        POS           ID         name   value
<dbl>     <chr>        <chr>       <chr>   <dbl>
 1     1 31439_T_A ENSG00000232325 indv1     1
 2     1 31439_T_A ENSG00000232325 indv2     1
 3     1 31439_T_A ENSG00000232325 indv3     2
 4     1 31504_G_A ENSG00000242474 indv1     2
 5     1 31504_G_A ENSG00000242474 indv2     1
 6     1 31504_G_A ENSG00000242474 indv3     1
 7     1 34713_A_C ENSG00000242474 indv1     1
 8     1 34713_A_C ENSG00000242474 indv2     0
 9     1 34713_A_C ENSG00000242474 indv3     1
10     1 34918_C_T ENSG00000242474 indv1     1
11     1 34918_C_T ENSG00000242474 indv2     0
12     1 34918_C_T ENSG00000242474 indv3     1
13     1 35119_G_A ENSG00000239715 indv1     0
14     1 35119_G_A ENSG00000239715 indv2     0
15     1 35119_G_A ENSG00000239715 indv3     1

view(DF_2)
name    ENSG00000232325  ENSG00000242474  ENSG00000239715  
indv1       0.1                0.4              0.22
indv2       0.3              -0.003            0.0001
indv3      -0.02               0.1              0.1
```

The desired output:

```
> OUTPUT
CHR       POS            ID         name   value  expr
<dbl>    <chr>          <chr>      <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1 31439_T_A ENSG00000232325 indv1     1    0.1
 2     1 31439_T_A ENSG00000232325 indv2     1    0.3 
 3     1 31439_T_A ENSG00000232325 indv3     2   -0.02
 4     1 31504_G_A ENSG00000242474 indv1     2    0.4
 5     1 31504_G_A ENSG00000242474 indv2     1   -0.003
 6     1 31504_G_A ENSG00000242474 indv3     1    0.1
 7     1 34713_A_C ENSG00000242474 indv1     1    0.4
 8     1 34713_A_C ENSG00000242474 indv2     0   -0.003
 9     1 34713_A_C ENSG00000242474 indv3     1    0.1
10     1 34918_C_T ENSG00000242474 indv1     1    0.4
11     1 34918_C_T ENSG00000242474 indv2     0   -0.003
12     1 34918_C_T ENSG00000242474 indv3     1    0.1
13     1 35119_G_A ENSG00000239715 indv1     0    0.22
14     1 35119_G_A ENSG00000239715 indv2     0   0.0001
15     1 35119_G_A ENSG00000239715 indv3     1    0.1
```

thanks!

Comment: Do you need a data table based answer? If not, try `tidyr::pivot_longer` followed by `dplyr::inner_join`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)

# create example data
DF_1 <- tribble(
  ~CHR, ~POS, ~ID, ~name, ~value,
  1, "1 31439_T_A", "ENSG00000232325", "indv1", 1,
  2, "1 31439_T_A", "ENSG00000232325", "indv2", 1,
  3, "1 31439_T_A", "ENSG00000232325", "indv3", 2,
)
DF_2 <- tribble(
  ~name, ~ENSG00000232325, ~ENSG00000242474, ~ENSG00000239715,
  "indv1", 0.1, 0.4, 0.22,
  "indv2", 0.3, -0.003, 0.0001,
  "indv3", -0.02, 0.1, 0.1
)

DF_2 %>%
  pivot_longer(-name, names_to = "ID", values_to = "expr") %>%
  inner_join(DF_1)
#> Joining, by = c("name", "ID")
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#>   name  ID               expr   CHR POS         value
#>   <chr> <chr>           <dbl> <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>
#> 1 indv1 ENSG00000232325  0.1      1 1 31439_T_A     1
#> 2 indv2 ENSG00000232325  0.3      2 1 31439_T_A     1
#> 3 indv3 ENSG00000232325 -0.02     3 1 31439_T_A     2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

data.table approach

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[melt(setDT(df2), id="name",value.name = "expr"), on=.(name, ID=variable)]
```

OUTPUT

```
    CHR         POS              ID  name value    expr
 1:   1 1 31439_T_A ENSG00000232325 indv1     1  0.1000
 2:   2 1 31439_T_A ENSG00000232325 indv2     1  0.3000
 3:   3 1 31439_T_A ENSG00000232325 indv3     2 -0.0200
 4:   4 1 31504_G_A ENSG00000242474 indv1     2  0.4000
 5:   7 1 34713_A_C ENSG00000242474 indv1     1  0.4000
 6:  10 1 34918_C_T ENSG00000242474 indv1     1  0.4000
 7:   5 1 31504_G_A ENSG00000242474 indv2     1 -0.0030
 8:   8 1 34713_A_C ENSG00000242474 indv2     0 -0.0030
 9:  11 1 34918_C_T ENSG00000242474 indv2     0 -0.0030
10:   6 1 31504_G_A ENSG00000242474 indv3     1  0.1000
11:   9 1 34713_A_C ENSG00000242474 indv3     1  0.1000
12:  12 1 34918_C_T ENSG00000242474 indv3     1  0.1000
13:  13 1 35119_G_A ENSG00000239715 indv1     0  0.2200
14:  14 1 35119_G_A ENSG00000239715 indv2     0  0.0001
15:  15 1 35119_G_A ENSG00000239715 indv3     1  0.1000
```